# Set Animation atFab Background

Tags: android, animation, gradient, floating-action-button

I have this have this FloatingActionButton:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_circle_black_24dp"
        android:tint="@color/white"
        android:background="@drawable/animation_list">
</android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton>
```

And I want to change the Color of the floatingActionButton with an Animation:

I have this Code:

```
    FloatingActionButton flab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    animationDrawable2 = (AnimationDrawable) flab.getBackground();
    animationDrawable2.setEnterFadeDuration(5000);
    animationDrawable2.setExitFadeDuration(2000);
```

But I get this Error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable
```

**EDIT:**
So here is my animation_list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_1"
    android:duration="6000" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_2"
    android:duration="6000" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_3"
    android:duration="6000" /> </animation-list>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Share `animation_list `.

Comment: @azizbekian With the animation_list everything is correct. I tested it for RelativeLayout ...Should I share it?

Comment: Yes, sir, share it.

Comment: @azizbekian See Edit:)